# ping_status in JSON REST API

Tags: posts, rest-api, json, plugin-json-api

**What is ping_status in JSON schema of wordpress REST API? And what is it's use cases?**. The official documentation is not much explain about it - [Posts|REST API Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [WordPress Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/pings_open/), pings tells **Whether the current post is open for pings.**

In human words, **A ping is a “this site has new content” notification** that invites search engine bots to visit your blog.

For more info, have a look at [this blog article](https://trafficgenerationcafe.com/wordpress-ping-list-2012/).